# How to access an element deep inside shadow-root

Tags: javascript, html, css, vaadin, lit-element

How can I access an element which is deep inside the shadow-root?

```
<vaadin-combo-box>
        #shadow-root
            <vaadin-text-field id="input">
                <vaadin-combo-box-dropdown-wrapper id="overlay">
                    #shadow-root(open)
                        <vaadin-combo-box-dropdown id="dropdown">
                            #shadow-root(open)
                                <vaadin-combo-box-overlay id="overlay">
                                    #shadow-root(open)
                                     <div part="overlay" id="overlay">
                                        <div part="content" id="conent">
                                            #shadow-root(open)
                                                <div id="scroller">
                                                    <iron-list id="selector">
                                                        #shadow-root(open)
                                                            <vaadin-combo-box-item>
                                                                ......
```

I want to style a **vaadin-combo-box-item** element but I don't know how to access this element.

Comment: I see some part attributes in there... can you ask Vaadin for export those CSS parts so that you can style them without piercing shadow roots?

Comment: In order to style a vaadin-combo-box-item, you might also want to consider using a ComponentRenderer (see https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/java-examples/presentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy answer to that because you have to access a very deep DOM element.

To make it little bit less painful you have to make a function which access provided shadow dom of element like this:

```js
const getShadowRoot = (elem, selector) => elem.shadowRoot.querySelector(selector);

const vaadinComboBox = getShadowRoot(document, 'vaadin-combo-box');
const vaadinTextField = getShadowRoot(vaadinComboBox, '#input');
const vaadinComboBoxWrapper = getShadowRoot(vaadinTextField, '#overlay');
const vaadinComboBoxDropdown = getShadowRoot(vaadinComboBoxWrapper, '#dropdown');
const vaadinComboBoxOverlay = getShadowRoot(vaadinComboBoxDropdown, '#overlay');
const vaadinComboBoxContent = getShadowRoot(vaadinComboBoxOverlay, '#conent');
const vaadinComboBoxSelector = getShadowRoot(vaadinComboBoxContent, '#selector');
const vaadinComboBoxItem = getShadowRoot(vaadinComboBoxContent, 'vaadin-combo-box-item');
```

Nevertheless, this amount of shadowDom elements looks like an architectural mistake

Comment: are you sure this is correct?
because when i am using 
```vaadinComboBoxItem.style.background = "green"```
nothing is happening

Comment: i think it will be elem.shadowRoot.querySelector(selector)

Comment: Function `getShadowRoot` returns `shadowRoot` attribute every time, so you don't have to access it every time. Maybe parent of `<vaadin-combo-box>` is not body but also shadow root?

Comment: ya parent of <vaadin-combo-box> is also shadow root

Comment: `<vaadin-dialog-overlay>
     #shadow-root
        .........
          <vaadin-combo-box>
              ........
`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an answer to get an element at an arbitrary depth. This is what I came up with; you can use a function of the sorts to recursively descend into the shadow DOM, to get either the parent or the element itself:

```js
function* descend(el, sel, parent) {
        if (el.matches(sel)) {
            yield parent ? el.parentElement : el;
        }
        if (el.shadowRoot) {
            for (const child of el.shadowRoot.children) {
                yield* descend(child, sel, parent);
            }
        }
        for (const child of el.children) {
            yield* descend(child, sel, parent);
        }
    };
```

Example use:

```js
const vid = [...descend(window.parent.document.querySelector("body"), "video", false)][0]
```